# 403 ERROR The request could not be satisfied in CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cloud, amazon-cloudfront

I have configured GoDaddy domain to use AWS DNS servers using this configuration:

[image]

When I open the internal cloudfront address xxxxxx.cloudfront.net it's working fine. But when I tried to open the domain into wen browser I get:

```
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: xxxxxxxAo1GT2z_7tnHBclkfaBZUH9qSOGCu_2U6xX8qJDbjw==
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Have you added this alias to the CloudFront distribution?

Comment: Yes I tried but I managed to do it after I added my SSL certificate. I managed to solve the issue.